# How to connect the Sennheiser Ew100 g3 to a DSLR camera without the CL 1 accessory cable?

Tags: sennheiser, cable+

I lost the CL 1 accessory cable for the Sennheiser Ew100 g3 wireless microphone and now cannot connect it to my DSLR camera (Nikon D610).

I noticed that the cable I lost had two jacks on both ends, one regular 3.5mm and the other was a 1/8in miniplug (whatever that is). I tried a cable with two regular 3.5mm jacks on both ends and I only get audio in one channel. What are my options now? Can I buy some kind of adapter which will turn a regular 3.5mm jack into a 3.5 miniplug?

Btw what are these miniplugs? I noticed that some microphones have them. Why don't they just use a regular 3.5mm?

Thanks for help.
Greg